# Using Apache over WC Portal, the jsessionid cookie is not recorded

Tags: apache, portal, jsessionid, webcenter

I have the following schema when regarding servers redirection:

1-Apache OHS (port 7274) has a VirtualHost configured to redirect requests do the WebCenter server. The configuration has been done as below:

```
NameVirtualHost *:7274
<VirtualHost *:7274>
    <Directory "${ORACLE_INSTANCE}/config/${COMPONENT_TYPE}/${COMPONENT_NAME}/htdocs2">
       Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order deny,allow 
       Allow from All   
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot "${ORACLE_INSTANCE}/config/${COMPONENT_TYPE}/${COMPONENT_NAME}/htdocs2"    
    <Location /myapp>
      SetHandler weblogic-handler
      PathTrim /myapp
      WeblogicHost myhost
      WeblogicPort myport
    </Location> 
</VirtualHost>
```

When I'm using Apache ohs over webcenter portal, the jsessionid cookie is not recorded into browser client. However, if I pass over the apache ohs, accessing directly the webcenter portal server, the JSESSIONID cookie is correctly recorded.

My weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<weblogic-application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd"
xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application">
<xml>
<parser-factory>
<saxparser-factory>oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory</saxparser-factory>
<document-builder-factory>oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilderFactory</document-builder-factory>
<transformer-factory>oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXTransformerFactory</transformer-factory>
</parser-factory>
</xml>
<listener>
<listener-class>oracle.adf.share.weblogic.listeners.ADFApplicationLifecycleListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>oracle.mds.lcm.weblogic.WLLifecycleListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>oracle.webcenter.lifecycle.listener.FeatureMetricApplicationListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<library-ref>
<library-name>adf.oracle.domain</library-name>
</library-ref>
<library-ref>
<library-name>oracle.jsp.next</library-name>
</library-ref>
<library-ref>
<library-name>oracle.webcenter.framework</library-name>
<specification-version>11.1.1</specification-version>
</library-ref>
<library-ref>
<library-name>oracle.webcenter.skin</library-name>
<specification-version>11.1.1</specification-version>
</library-ref>
<library-ref>
<library-name>oracle.sdp.client</library-name>
</library-ref>
</weblogic-application>
```

Do you have any concern about my configuration?